# Is it safe to deallocate oneself on WM_NCDESTROY?

Tags: c++, winapi

Consider the following code snippet:

```
// MyWindow.h
struct MyWindow
{
    LRESULT CALLBACK myWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    static LRESULT CALLBACK myWindowProcWrapper(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};
extern MyWindow *windowPtr; // windowPtr is initialized on startup using raw new

// MyWindow.cpp
MyWindow *windowPtr = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWindow::myWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        delete windowPtr;
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWindow::myWindowProcWrapper(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return windowPtr->myWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The question is whether the given code snippet is safe as written.

Basically, `MyWindow` is the class for a window created with the WinAPI. I need to do some final cleanup when the window is destroyed.

Notice that the instance of `MyWindow`, `windowPtr`, is created using a raw `new`. I have to delete the instance somewhere in a member function, so I delete the reference to the object itself from within a member function.

The code relies on the assumption that `WM_NCDESTROY` is the last message ever received by that window.

So the questions are as follows:

- Is it safe to assume that `WM_NCDESTROY` is always the last message a window receives and to perform final cleanup there?
- Is the listed code safe? If not, under what conditions could it break?

*Remark: I'm only interested in whether the code is technically safe, not if it is good practice to use a raw new and/or global variables. I have some good reasons for this implementation.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not explicitly documented, that `WM_NCDESTROY` is the final message a window receives. If you read in between the lines, you can deduce this information, though.

The documentation for [WM_NCDESTROY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632636.aspx) contains the following remark:

> This message frees any memory internally allocated for the window.

[Window Features: Window Destruction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#destruction) outlines the consequences of this:

> When a window is destroyed, the system [...] removes any internal data associated with the window. **This invalidates the window handle**, which can no longer be used by the application.

Putting those together, destroying a window invalidates its window handle. Once the `WM_NCDESTROY` message handler has run to completion, the window handle is no longer valid. An invalid window handle no longer receives any messages.

Your implementation is thus safe.

It is doubtful that any of these rules will change in the future (with so many applications relying on `WM_NCDESTROY` being the final message), but if you want to be prepared, you might want to consider placing a `windowPtr = nullptr;` statement following `delete windowPtr;`. Doing so ensures, that your application fails in a predictable way, in case it receives a message after the `MyWindow` instance has been disposed.

Comment: to be prepared WM_NCDESTROY being the final message - need simply not call member function from static wrapper after `WM_NCDESTROY` , but however if unconditionally call `delete this` in `myWindowProc` - may be unsafe, because myWindowProc can be called recursively - as result we can be inside `myWindowProc` after `this` already deleted. i describe concrete variants how this can happens

Comment: @RbMm: *"The question is whether the given code snippet is safe as it is currently."* The given code sample doesn't lead to recursive calls.

Comment: question was - "Is it safe to deallocate one self on WM_NCDESTROY" - and in general case no. situation when WindowProc called recursive (indirect of course) very common. and the current code only for clarity - you not think that real `MyWindowProc` containing only `WM_NCDESTOY` handler and nothing do more ?

Comment: @RbMm: I'm not going to read the question for you again. Can we stop this now? You provided your answer. That should be sufficient to make your point. No need to bother me.

Answer (score 1):

yes, `WM_NCDESTROY` is the last message sended to `WindowProc` (how minimum now).

but direct, unconditionally call `delete this` in `myWindowProc` can be unsafe in complex case and produce very bad error (because hard to found)

you not take to account that `myWindowProc` can be called recursively.

let us first consider a simple version:

```
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE)
        {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }
```

so we destroy window on `ESCAPE` pressed. in this case `myWindowProc` will be called recursively with `WM_NCDESTROY` where we `delete this` and then we return to up level `myWindowProc` (for `WM_KEYDOWN` ). but at this point `this` already destroyed and invalid. so we must not more access any members fields or virtual functions. good if we call direct `DefWindowProc` in the end of own `WindowProc`. but what be if say our class implement and call `virtual LRESULT DefWinProc(..)` for allow overwrite `DefWindowProc` behaviour ? (say to `DefMDIChildProc` ) ?

now more complex case - assume you implement some child control. based on `WM_SOMETHING_1` you set `WM_NOTIFY_SOMETHING_1` to parent (via `SendMessage` ). and parent decide call `DestrowWindow` when handle this notify (for self, and as result for all childs). so internally your call `delete this` and when you return from `SendMessage(..WM_NOTIFY_SOMETHING_1..)` your `this` already will be deleted, but you will not even know about this.

access `this` after it will be deleted real in complex windows case, and if we modify some member data - can be not direct crash(which is good for detection) but heap corruption, which will manifest itself later and this is very hard to detect.

however for this exist 100% correct solution, which will be work even if `WM_NCDESTROY` will be not final message for window.

we must not use global `MyWindow *windowPtr` but assign it to window data via `GWLP_USERDATA` and remove on `WM_NCDESTROY` . and call `myWindowProc` only when `GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA)` return not 0 . in this case even if will some WM_* message after `WM_NCDESTROY` - static `myWindowProcWrapper` not call `myWindowProc` and we must use reference counting for MyWindow class :

1. call `AddRef();` before `SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA,(LONG_PTR)windowPtr);`
2. call `Release();` after `SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, 0);`
3. wrap `windowPtr->myWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam)` in
   `AddRef(); Release();`
4. call `delete this` only from `Release` and make `~MyWindow()`
   `private:`

with this rules we can absolute safe access this pointer in `myWindowProc` at any time and any situation. and not dependening about `WM_NCDESTROY` is the last message

```
struct MyWindow
{
private:
    PSTR _somedata;
    LONG _dwRef;

public:

    MyWindow() : _dwRef(1), _somedata(0)
    {
    }

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&_dwRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwRef)) delete this;
    }

    static LRESULT CALLBACK myWindowProcWrapper(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        MyWindow *windowPtr;

        if (msg == WM_NCCREATE)
        {
            windowPtr = (MyWindow *)((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->lpCreateParams;

            windowPtr->AddRef();
            SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)windowPtr);
        }
        else
        {
            windowPtr = (MyWindow *)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
        }

        LRESULT lr;

        if (windowPtr)
        {
            windowPtr->AddRef();
            lr = windowPtr->myWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
            windowPtr->Release();
        }
        else
        {
            lr = DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }

        if (msg == WM_NCDESTROY && windowPtr)
        {
            SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, 0);
            windowPtr->Release();
        }

        return lr;
    }

protected:

    LRESULT CALLBACK myWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE)
            {
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
                DbgPrint("%s\n", _somedata);// bug can be here if not use ref semantic
            }
            break;

        case WM_CREATE:
            if (_somedata = new CHAR[64])
            {
                strcpy(_somedata, "1234567890");
            }
            break;
        }
        // bug can be here if not use ref semantic, because myDefWinProc virtual
        return myDefWinProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        //return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    // for demo only here, not need in simply case
    virtual LRESULT myDefWinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

private:

    ~MyWindow()
    {
        if (_somedata) delete _somedata;
    }
};


    if (MyWindow* p = new MyWindow)
    {
        CreateWindowEx(0, L"lpszClassName", L"lpWindowName", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, HWND_DESKTOP, 0, 0, p);
        p->Release();
    }
```

Comment: `GWLP_USERDATA` is generally the wrong place to store window-private data. It is accessible to everyone, and everyone **is** abusing it. Better solutions are *cbWndExtra* (in case you registered the class), or calling `SetProp` if you didn't register the window class.

Comment: @IInspectable - SetProp also "accessible to everyone", but task not in this -what you mean at all under "accessible to everyone" ? so what ? you assume some malicious code in your process ? I think that `GWLP_USERDATA` the best place for store class pointer

Comment: With `SetProp` you have to know the name. That makes it private. And no, I do not mean malicious code. I mean code, that tries to be good (like yours), but then gets it wrong by writing to memory that's not owned by the caller. `GWLP_USERDATA` belongs to whoever called `RegisterClass`. It's not clear from your code, whether that is the case or not. And if you **did** call `RegisterClass`, why don't you allocate private *cbWndExtra* memory, that is a lot less likely to be tampered with, because other code cannot rely on it being there (in contrast to `GWLP_USERDATA`)?

Comment: @IInspectable - GWLP_USERDATA - is per window not per class. different windows of same class can have different data for GWLP_USERDATA . so you comment is wrong. "GWLP_USERDATA belongs to whoever called RegisterClass" - absolute not true

Comment: You see, that is why **you** shouldn't be using it. You clearly do not understand the ownership semantics here. Yes, `GWLP_USERDATA` is allocated per window instance, but it is allocated for private use by the window procedure registered through the call to `RegisterClass`. That makes whoever called `RegisterClass` the owner of the per-window private `GWLP_USERDATA`.

Comment: @IInspectable - **GWLP_USERDATA** - *Sets the user data associated with the window. This data is intended for use by the application that created the window. Its value is initially zero.*  we can have multiple windows of the **same** class with different GWLP_USERDATA for every window

Comment: As I said, *"`GWLP_USERDATA` is allocated per window instance"*. I don't see, how that is in conflict with the documentation. That doesn't make it yours, though. [The bonus window bytes at GWLP_USERDATA](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050303-00/?p=36293) *"belong to the window class and not to the code that creates the window."*

Comment: @IInspectable - you not read comments here :) - "When I wrote that the values "belong to the window class", I meant that only the window class implementor may read or write the values. Think of them as private members of the window class. Code that calls CreateWindow is a customer of the window class and should not be messing with the window class’s private data without permission"

Comment: Not sure, what point you are trying to make here. That comment tells you, that the code you suggested in this proposed answer is likely wrong. It fumbles with data that it doesn't own. Both the blog entry and this comment by Raymond Chen **clearly** illustrate, who `GWLP_USERDATA` belongs to. You are just having difficulty comprehending.

Comment: @IInspectable - sorry me for bad english. may be i not understand you. are you try to say next - if i create 2 windows (hwnd) of **same** windows class - i can not set **different** `GWLP_USERDATA ` for **different** hwnds ?

Comment: @IInspectable - and if you can view my code I get/set `GWLP_USERDATA`  in class function ! `myWindowProcWrapper` - again here all **absolute** correct from any view

Comment: No, I'm saying exactly, what the blog entry says: The caller of `CreateWindow` does not own the data. The caller of `RegisterClass` does. This does not imply, that `GWLP_USERDATA` is allocated per class. It is allocated per window, but it **belongs** to the class, and only the window procedure registered by the window class is allowed to modify it.

Comment: @IInspectable- "but it belongs to the class, and only the window procedure registered by the window class is allowed to modify it." - **YES** but I and do exactly this !!! in `myWindowProcWrapper`

Comment: @IInspectable - myWindowProcWrapper - is windows procedure, registered with class (`wc.lpfnWndProc = MyWindow::myWindowProcWrapper;`) and only in this func I access `GWLP_USERDATA`.

Comment: As I said, this is not clear from the code you posted. For all we know, it could be a subclassed window procedure. If you do register the window class, the safer alternative is to allocate *cbWndExtra* memory to store the C++ class instance pointer. This memory belongs to the window class as well, but it isn't abused by external code that doesn't own it.

Comment: @IInspectable - I even could not have imagined that `GWLP_USERDATA` create such discussion. however I say that use `GWLP_USERDATA` for own class or standard windows controls - *the best* way to bind data pointer with window. not need use any `cbWndExtra` - for why ?? when `GWLP_USERDATA` always exist and free for as

Comment: Just as I thought that you finally learned, that `GWLP_USERDATA` belongs to the window class, you turn around and suggest to abuse a standard Windows control's **private** data. No, `GWLP_USERDATA` of a button control **does not belong to you**. You must not use it. It belongs to the window class. If you need to store data with a window of a window class you did not register, you have to settle for `SetProp`.

Comment: @IInspectable - you mistake. we can use GWLP_USERDATA  for standard windows controls - like button,edit, etc

Comment: Exactly. You can use it, although it doesn't belong to you. And since you and many others wouldn't know, or even consider, that you are treading foreign territory,  you cannot safely use `GWLP_USERDATA`. What would happen, if a Button control decided to use it for its own implementation? What if two applications tried to pull that stunt? `GWLP_USERDATA` is pretty much useless these days, because of hordes of developers sharing your mindset. That, and [misleading documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, when use `GWLP_USERDATA` for not own class exist problem of who is **owner** of this data here. in case windows controls - can assume that this is who create control. others really must use another way for subclass. for **self** registered class - we can **absolute safe** use `GWLP_USERDATA` - and here is this case. however we digress from OP question - are safe `delete this` on `WM_NCDESTROY` - I point that can be problems here, if not use reference count

Comment: *"in case windows controls - can assume that this is who create control."* - That assumption is unfounded and unsafe. Don't assume anything, when you know the answer already. `GWLP_USERDATA` belongs to the control implementation, not you. And since you (and many others) would readily violate ownership rules, using `GWLP_USERDATA` for classes you registered becomes unsafe just as well. It's hard to follow your line of reasoning, where you believe that everyone must honor ownership for your classes, while you are free to violate everyone else's property.

Comment: In other words: **You** are part of the problem, why using `GWLP_USERDATA` has become unsafe, so don't act as though it were. It isn't, and I provided two alternatives already, that **are** safe. And this is not off-topic either. You offered code that cannot be made safe, which I pointed out. It's hard to understand, why you aren't going with one of the alternatives.

Comment: @IInspectable - again - I use `GWLP_USERDATA` for **my own class** - this is absolute safe and the best way here. about windows controls - this is separate discussion. but how about OP initial question ? `delete this` on WM_NCDESTROY inconditionally

Comment: i always use `GWLP_USERDATA` for own class, for other (not mine) windows subclassing i usually use "ATL style" stub window proc, where stored pointer to class and jump to real WindowProc. so only WNPROC need overwrite. and about third-party controls I nothing say - here of course we can not use USERDATA

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Self deallocate is safe in WM_NCDESTROY.
But just to be sure your program will not fail under Wine, for example, I'd recommend to set windowPtr to null after delete, and check it before call windowPtr->myWindowProc.
And, ofcause, it must be only window of that wndclass.

Comment: *"it must be only window of that wndclass"* - [No](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#destruction): *"Destroying a window does not affect the window class from which the window is created. New windows can still be created using that class, and any existing windows of that class continue to operate."*

Comment: If there are more than one windows of this wndclass in the same time, then destroying one of them will delete the only windowPtr, and any window message after that will cause exception

Comment: This is a corollary of the C++ class instance pointer being (presumably) a global resource, and doesn't pertain to whether or not it is safe to delete the C++ class instance in a `WM_NCDESTROY` handler. Besides, dereferencing a dangling pointer will not raise an exception. The behavior is undefined, and it might raise an exception, although that is very unlikely to happen here.

Comment: So in Wine it might happen that WM_NCDESTROY isn't the very last message (why would that happen)? 

I can of course null the pointer after destruction and add a check whether windowPtr is non zero before calling  windowPtr->myWindowProc. But what should the function do/return in that case?